# Do scheduled tasks stop a c# program from looping?

Tags: c#, window

I have a C# program; when I run it manually, it hits an external API and then updates several tables in my database by looping over a `SqlDataReader`.

It would appear that when I set it to run as a scheduled task, it only ever updates the very first result in the first table it hits, almost as if it encountered an error somewhere, but when I run it manually (I have been running it manually for almost two weeks with no error), it updates all records in all tables.

Is there something that stops the task scheduler running things like this?

I haven't posted any code as it doesn't seem relevant to the actual question in hand.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any logging in your application to see if an exception is occurring? I'd also add some verbose logging of the process so you can determine what is working.

I've had issues with windows services before and adding verbose logging helps you see what is going on.

Are you sure the scheduled task is running under an account that has the relevant permissions?